# New line in python?

Tags: python

Want to find piece of the code, written in python, which adds a new line inside some function.

For which character I have to search? For `\n` ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, in strings usually `\n` is used. However, it might be multi line string like this:

```
'''
Some string
with 
enters.
'''
```

Answer (score 2):

The newline you are looking for might be added implicitly: watch out for Python's print statement.  It automatically adds a newline if the last argument is not followed by a comma.

Answer (score 0):

In order to add a new line in a python string you use  `\n`
for example:

```
#Code
string = "Hello\nWorld"
print(string)
```

```
#Result
Hello
World
```